# Highlight entering text in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to compare edit text and view text and highlight right words with green color and wrong words with red color. But this code for any right word it colors the entire text in green and entire text red for any wrong word. Please help..

```
    tview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tview); 
    tview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tview1); 

    simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.simpleEditText); 
    fullStory=tvpass1.getText().toString(); 
    etValue=simpleEditText.getText().toString(); 


    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tview.setText("Time:  " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            tview.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tview.setText("Time Up!");
            tview.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            simpleEditText.setEnabled(false);
            simpleEditText.clearFocus();

        }
    }.start();

    simpleEditText. addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,  int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int before) {

                String etValue= simpleEditText. getText().toString();
```

//text=text.replace("\n", "") ;

```
                String[] EtStArray = etValue.split("\\s+");
                String[] VtStArray = fullStory.split("\\s+");  
//              tview.setText("Words =" +EtStArray.length);

            if((EtStArray.length>1) && ( j!=EtStArray.length))
                {
                    //      word=EtStArray[i];


                    if(EtStArray[i].equals(VtStArray[i]))
                    {     
                        tview1.append(EtStArray[i]+" ");
                        tview1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else
                    {     
                        tview1.append(EtStArray[i]+" ");
                        tview1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    i++;
                    j=EtStArray.length;
                }  

         //   tview1.setText(etValue);
            //tview1.setText(VtStArray[0]);
        }  

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged( Editable s) {
     } 
     }) ; 

     }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableStringBuilder like this code sample

```
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
  SpannableStringBuilder builder = new 
  SpannableStringBuilder(textView.getText().toString());

  ForegroundColorSpan redSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
  ForegroundColorSpan whiteSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE);
  ForegroundColorSpan blueSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE);
  ForegroundColorSpan greenSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
  ForegroundColorSpan yellowSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);


  builder.setSpan(redSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  builder.setSpan(whiteSpan, 1, 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
  builder.setSpan(blueSpan, 2, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  builder.setSpan(greenSpan, 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  builder.setSpan(yellowSpan, 4,5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    //setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags)
    //Mark the specified range of text with the specified object.

  textView.setText(builder);
```

about more
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder